# Move selected text to right/left

Tags: delphi

How to move selected source text to left or right in Delphi 2007 code editor? I need short key command. Is it possible at all in Delphi 2007? How about other versions? Is it possible to manage this with any additional tools?

Comment: My first guess when reading this is tab/space to move to right and shift-tab or backspace for left but can you give an example of what you need?

Comment: If you mean in code editor, then you can use `CTRL + K → I` for indent and `CTRL + K → U` for unindent.

Comment: You could read the documentation which has a comprehensive list: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts

Comment: For future reference: The portion of your question related to "any additional tools" is off-topic here; we do not allow questions asking for tool or library recommendations or links to off-site resources; this is explained in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indent/outdent (unindent) selected text in the Code Editor with the default keymapping using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Indent) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (Unindent).

(Recent versions of the IDE use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to do this as well.)

If you're using another key mapping (such as Brief or Visual Studio), you can find a list of the key mappings in the help file under **Key Mappings**; the individual key assignments are listed there.

Comment: Classic key mapping (wordstar): Indent ctrl-k-i and unindent ctrl-k-u.

Comment: Classic (Wordstar) here too.